# How to access Local file system using Silverlight 4 (Webbrowser control)

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Our Silverlight application needs to show to the user previews of HTML pages it generates dynamically, so we want to use the WebBrowser to show these pages. The problem is that the HTML contains links to other local files such as images, flash objects, CSS and javascript files. The CSS and javascript could be placed inline in the HTML, but I haven't found a way to embed images. Something simple like this just doesn't work:

Creating the HTML file and the image file in the isolated storage is doable, but I can't get the path to the created HTML file to pass on to WebBrowser.Navigate(uri).

Reading the contents of the HTML file and calling WebBrowser.NavigateToString(string) will show the page, but not any linked images or scripts.

Linking to online sources is not an option as the application needs to work offline (i.e. out of browser) and performance would be much better if the images and flash objects were able to be cached locally.

So, is there any way in Silverlight of showing in the WebBrowser control a local HTML file that contains an image from the local file system, or is it impossible?

Thanks, sandeep agrawal

Comment: did you get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make that work is to make the Silverlight an OOB application, and then you can still only access the My* folders.

I heard that someone wrote a browser control that can be used without going OOB but not sure about that.  This is a real pain, but a necessary one I guess.